# Flink DataSet.map get 'error: missing parameter type'

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am just start to learn Scala and Flink. When I try to run demo codes as follow:

```
private def demoFunction[T <: Vector](dataSet: DataSet[T])
  : DataSet[(linalg.Vector[Double], linalg.Vector[Double])] = {

  val metrics = dataSet.map{
    v => (1.0, v.asBreeze, linalg.Vector.zeros[Double](v.size))
  }.reduce{
    // reduce code..
  }
  // ...
}
```

I got err info:

```
Error: missing parameter type v => (1.0, v.asBreeze, linalg.Vector.zeros[Double](v.size))
```

The dependencies are follow:

- linalg: import breeze.linalg
- DataSet: import org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet
- Vector: a custom trait
- Scala==2.12.8, JDK==1.8

If you have any ideas, please help. Thanks in advance.

---

Update on December 12.

I fix this problem after adding a *:T* after *v*, It seems to clarify which type *v* is. But I am still confused with it.

```
val metrics = dataSet.map{
  v:T => (1.0, v.asBreeze, linalg.Vector.zeros[Double](v.size))
}// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Vector` in `T <: Vector` is the same as `linalg.Vector` then it takes a type parameter

```
trait Vector[@spec(Int, Double, Float) V] extends VectorLike[V, Vector[V]] { 
...
```

so it can't be just `T <: Vector`, it should be `T <: Vector[...something...]`.

If `Vector` in `T <: Vector` is different from `linalg.Vector`, then maybe you `import breeze.linalg._` and `Vector` is resolved as `linalg.Vector`. So use fully qualified name

```
private def demoFunction[T <: yourpackage.yoursubpackage.Vector] ...
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still has problem. I fix it by v:T => (1.0, v.asBreeze, linalg.Vector.zeros[Double](v.size))